# Can't add Menu item next to another

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-menu

I am trying to add Menu item(**action_collapse_expand**) next to another menu item. Problem is that item is added to expandable list(three dots icon), but not as separate icon. I've just started learning Android and I would like to know what am I doing wrong.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <!--For all properties see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html-->
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_collapse_expand"
        android:icon="@drawable/drag_drop"
        android:title="Collapse"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
    
  <item android:id="@+id/add" android:showAsAction="never" android:title="add" android:icon="@drawable/Add">
    <menu>
      <item android:id="@+id/map" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title="map" android:icon="@drawable/Map" />
      <item android:id="@+id/mapK" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:title=mapK" android:icon="@drawable/MapK" />
   
    </menu>
  </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/exit" android:showAsAction="always" android:title="Exit" android:icon="@drawable/Close" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `android:showAsAction` with `app:showAsAction`.

Don't forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` under your `menu` tag.